# Read and list exif data using vba

Tags: excel, vba, exif

I am trying to list EXIF data for each image in a folder, such as focal length and exposure time, in an excel spreadsheet. Does anyone have any pointers?  I have seen other method but only lists things like date created, etc., but never the EXIF data (in the "Details" tab in the image properties). I'm not sure this can even be done.

Comment: Did you try googling for "VBA exif" ? - there are examples to be found there...

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's a good question.
You could use exiv2 a command line tool to extract exif as well as iptc and xmp metadata.
   see http://www.exiv2.org/
You could call this tool from vba and get the results back as described in:
   http://programmersheaven.com/discussion/167592/return-value-of-shell

I wonder if there is an even simpler solution for that.